# Saving large quantity of String in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have to make a application to load images in excel vba, encrypt that image and save it in cells. My problem is the limit of characters in cell ( 32.767 characters ) and my encrypted string is like 800k characters.

I make a function to make a array of string with custom string character length to save in a row but when i save in cells i recive this error:

[image]

```
Public Function SplitString(ByVal TheString As String, ByVal StringLen As Integer) As String()
Dim ArrCount As Integer  'as it is declared locally, it will automatically reset to 0 when this is called again
Dim I As Long  'we are going to use it.. so declare it (with local scope to avoid breaking other code)
Dim TempArray() As String
ReDim TempArray((Len(TheString) - 1) \ StringLen)

For I = 1 To Len(TheString) Step StringLen
    TempArray(ArrCount) = Mid$(TheString, I, StringLen)
    ArrCount = ArrCount + 1
Next

SplitString = TempArray   'actually return the value
End Function

Dim StringArray As Variant
        StringArray = SplitString(EncodeFile(.SelectedItems(1)), 30000)

        Dim ind As Integer
        ind = 2

        For index = 1 To UBound(StringArray)
            Sheet5.Cells(55, ind).value = StringArray(index)
            ind = ind + 1
        Next index
```

I solve this problem by adding a delay in for loop but it's not a optimal solution

```
        For index = 1 To UBound(StringArray)
            Sheet5.Cells(55, ind).value = StringArray(index)
            ind = ind + 1
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
        Next index
```

And now the question: Can I make this more faster or a better way to solve this problem ?

Comment: Low hanging fruit alert: Why not use Long instead of Integer and get rid of ind and use index + 1 in its place inside Cells()? And does adding DoEvents instead of Wait help? Switch off screen-updating until operation complete. And is () on the end of the function signature required?

Comment: The problem isn't in SplitString Function, that function work but when i add array values returns from that functions it give me out of memory. And @QHarr, that index is a count for my cells because i add each element in a different cell in the same row.

EDIT: DoEvent give the same error

Comment: Yes... but it does the same thing as Index so you are adding unnecessary lines of code I think.

Comment: Yep, i modify that instruction like you said, but still give the same error if i delete wait instruction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the array into the cells within one row without the loop.

```
Sheet5.Cells(55, "A").resize(1, ubound(StringArray) + 1) = StringArray
```

Comment: fwiw, if you were dropping a 1-D array into a number of cells within one column instead of one row, you would have to use application.transpose(StringArray).